# Capybara::ElementNotFound error - Super simple Capybara example is failing and I have no clue as to why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

Here's my code. I've been messing around with this for 1.5 hours and have yet to get Capybara to click a link without the ElementNotFound error. Visiting the site works as expected, but clicking links, filling in forms--really, interacting with the DOM in any fashion--fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'

class Prowler
  include Capybara::DSL

  def initialize
    Capybara.run_server = false
        Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  end

  def visitSite
    session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
    session.visit "https://www.cnn.com"
    click_link 'Entertainment'
  end
end

prowler = Prowler.new
prowler.visitSite
```

Comment: Have you tried using the xpath? Eg. `locate("//[@id='overlay'").find("//h1").click`

Comment: No. I just want to figure out why this isn't working. This is all but a "hello world" example, and it keeps failing.

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because you're not calling click_link on the session where you visited a URL.  By including Capybara::DSL you've made all of Capybaras methods available on the object, and when you call `click_link` you are actually calling `Capybara.current_session.click_link`.  However you've created your own session which isn't Capybara.current_session, so you either need to let Capybara manage the session (which in your use case probably won't work well since it seems like you want a session per class instance)

```
visit 'www.cnn.com'
click_link 'Entertainment'
```

or don't include Capybara::DSL and instead manage you're own session per class instance like you are doing and call the methods on the session

```
session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
session.visit "https://www.cnn.com"
session.click_link 'Entertainment'
```

see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-sessions